# Accessible PDF: tab follows tag-structure

Tags: pdf, tags, accessibility

I have to create PDFs from ODT Files. I'm using this script: https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter

The PDFs must meet the following accessibility requirements:

```
1 .Document is marked as tagged
2. Document Title available
3. Document Language defined
4. Accessible Security Settings
5. Tab follows Tag-Structure
6. Consistent Heading Structure
7. Bookmarks available
8. Accessible Font Encodings
9. Content completely tagged
10. Logical Reading Order
11. Alternative Text available
12. Correct Syntax of Tags / Rolls
13. Sufficient contrast for Text
14.Spaces existent
```

Now i'm struggling at "Tab follows Tag-Structure". I use this tool to check the requirements: http://www.access-for-all.ch/en/pdf-lab/pdf-accessibility-checker-pac/download-pac.html

Can someone tell me how i can make the PDFs meet this requirement?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tab follows Tag-Structure

You cannot do this programmically I don't think. This is fairly easy to do in Acrobat:

1. open said PDF
2. open the Pages pane
3. select all of the pages
4. right-click, and choose properties
5. Choose the appropriate choice from the options.

Comment: I've seen a post of you where you've written that yo have looked at the tagging of a PDF ("I just looked at their sample PDF. It is tagged, but the quality of the tagging is extremely poor.", http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393362/creating-tagged-pdf-document-in-seam-itext?rq=1) Can you tell me how I can have a look at the tagging of a pdf?

Comment: You need Adobe Acrobat Pro to view/change tags. You cannot do it with Adobe Reader, and same goes for Adobe Acrobat Standard.

Comment: ok I have Acobat Pro now and managed to get tabs following tag structure. But where can i view the tag structure?

Comment: View > Show/hide > navigation panes > Tags. Also open the reading order onee

Comment: can you tell me why I got this <span>-tags around all my tags? for example the tag-structure for a Heading: Tags>Document>Heading1>span>title where it should be Tags>Document>Heading1>title

Comment: All depends on how the PDF is made. I spoken to somebody who is an industry leader in PDFs. Essentially the `span` PDF Tag is short for ex_span_sion, but if you do not supply an alt text (via tag properties) they are ignored aka they don't exsist. So you can either leave them as-is or remove them.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I found out what I had to do for this specific case: I had to remove fo:country="CH" from the text-properties of the standard style in the styles.xml of the ODT-Document. No idea why but it works now

Comment: That's interesting, can you share your source?

Comment: I meant, where did you find to remove fo:country

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends mainly on what tools you have available to do this. There are certainly options out there:

1) You can use the JavaScript interface Adobe Acrobat offers. One of its methods (setPageTabOrder) does exactly what you are looking for.

2) There are commercial tools out there that offer the same functionality. callas pdfToolbox for example (warning, I'm affiliated with this company) has a correction you can use to set the tab order of all pages to "Use document structure".

Comment: Unless the method you named in #1 sets it like in my answer, the issue will still be present

Comment: It would - it would just do it using JavaScript as opposed to using the user interface and punching the buttons as you suggested. The end result would be the same...